# How to transform a series or data frame column with continuous data into a categorical one based on a set of breaks in polars?

Tags: python-polars

A standard way to achieve this on R is by using `cut()` and in pandas using `pd.cut()`. This is a straight forward way to covert numerical data into categories than can be defined on the fly (usually referred to as `breaks`).

To not rewrite the wheel, I will refer to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut) for examples since they are much better than any one I could just improvise now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: as of Polars 0.13.57, there is now a [`cut`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.cut.html#polars.cut) function.

##### Polars version 0.13.56 and before

Polars does not have a cut function, per se.  However, one simple (and very performant) way to cut data is using [`join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html).

Let's start with this data.

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

sample_size = 10
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "var1": np.random.default_rng(seed=0).normal(0, 1, sample_size),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (10, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ var1      │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 0.1257    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.535669 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.361595  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.304     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.947081  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.703735 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -1.265421 │
└───────────┘
```

### The Algorithm

##### Step 1: Create a simple dataset with break points and cat variables

First, we'll create a DataFrame containing our break points, along with our categorical variable. Let's say we want break points of -1, 0, and 1.  We'll supply these in the constructor.

I'll also use [`with_row_count`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_count.html) to automatically generate our categorical values.  (If you like, you can assign something else for a categorical variable in the constructor.)

Note that the data type of your break points must match the data type of the variable that you are cutting.  Hence, in this simple example, I'm writing the first break point as "-1.0" (so that Polars automatically creates `break_pt` as `Float64`, rather than an integer.)

```py
break_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "break_pt": [-1.0, 0, 1],
    }
).with_row_count("binned")
break_df
```

```
>>> break_df
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬──────────┐
│ binned ┆ break_pt │
│ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ -1.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
└────────┴──────────┘
```

##### Step 2: Join using `join_asof`

Now we can perform the `join_asof`.  Note that **both** datasets must be sorted by the as_of keys, so we'll need to sort our DataFrame of random numbers by our continuous variable (`var1`) before the join.  (`break_df` is already sorted.).

```py
(
    df
    .sort(["var1"])
    .join_asof(
        break_df,
        left_on="var1",
        right_on="break_pt",
        strategy="forward",
    )
)
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ var1      ┆ binned ┆ break_pt │
│ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ u32    ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ -1.265421 ┆ 0      ┆ -1.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.703735 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.535669 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1257    ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.361595  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.947081  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.304     ┆ null   ┆ null     │
└───────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

This leaves us with the last bin (the values above the last breakpoint) as `null`.  To fill these `null` values with a proper `binned` value, we can use [`fill_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html).

```py
(
    df
    .sort(["var1"])
    .join_asof(
        break_df,
        left_on="var1",
        right_on="break_pt",
        strategy="forward",
    )
    .with_column(pl.col("binned").fill_null(pl.col("binned").max() + 1))
)
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ var1      ┆ binned ┆ break_pt │
│ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ i64    ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ -1.265421 ┆ 0      ┆ -1.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.703735 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.535669 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 ┆ 1      ┆ 0.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1257    ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.361595  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.947081  ┆ 2      ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.304     ┆ 3      ┆ null     │
└───────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

### Performance

So how well does this perform?  Let's increase our random sample to 100 million values.  And let's expand our breaklist to ~6,000 break points.

```py
sample_size = 100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "var1": np.random.default_rng(seed=0).normal(0, 1, sample_size),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (100000000, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ var1      │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 0.1257    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.714924 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.269947  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -2.3158   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.383743 │
└───────────┘
```

```py
break_list = [next_val / 1000 for next_val in range(-3000, 3001)]

break_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "break_pt": break_list,
    }
).with_row_count("binned")
break_df
```

```
>>> break_df
shape: (6001, 2)
┌────────┬──────────┐
│ binned ┆ break_pt │
│ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ -3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ -2.999   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ -2.998   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ -2.997   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5997   ┆ 2.997    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5998   ┆ 2.998    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5999   ┆ 2.999    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6000   ┆ 3.0      │
└────────┴──────────┘
```

And now timing the algorithm itself...

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
(
    df.sort(["var1"])
    .join_asof(
        break_df,
        left_on="var1",
        right_on="break_pt",
        strategy="forward",
    )
    .with_column(pl.col("binned").fill_null(pl.col("binned").max() + 1))
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (100000000, 3)
┌───────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ var1      ┆ binned ┆ break_pt │
│ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ i64    ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ -5.666706 ┆ 0      ┆ -3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -5.6048   ┆ 0      ┆ -3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -5.428571 ┆ 0      ┆ -3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -5.350106 ┆ 0      ┆ -3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...       ┆ ...    ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.327897  ┆ 6001   ┆ null     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.344677  ┆ 6001   ┆ null     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.386379  ┆ 6001   ┆ null     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.4829    ┆ 6001   ┆ null     │
└───────────┴────────┴──────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
3.107058142999449
```

Just over 3 seconds.

### Edit: Some helpful additions/improvements

Some improvements that we can make:

- adding the capacity for labels, either default labels or a specified list of labels
- returning the labels as a categorical variable
- allowing the list of cut values to be passed as integers
- encapsulating the algorithm into a callable function

```py
from typing import List
def cut_dataframe(_df: pl.DataFrame,
                  var_nm: str,
                  bins: List[float],
                  labels: List[str] = None) -> pl.DataFrame:

    cuts_df = pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series(
            name="break_pt",
            values=bins,
            dtype=pl.Float64
        ).extend_constant(np.Inf, 1)
    ])

    if labels:
        cuts_df = cuts_df.with_column(
            pl.Series(
                name="category",
                values=labels
            )
        )
    else:
        cuts_df = cuts_df.with_column(
            pl.format(
                "({}, {}]",
                pl.col("break_pt").shift_and_fill(1, -np.Inf),
                pl.col("break_pt"),
            )
            .alias("category")
        )

    cuts_df = cuts_df.with_column(pl.col("category").cast(pl.Categorical))

    result = (
        _df.sort([var_nm]).join_asof(
            cuts_df,
            left_on=var_nm,
            right_on="break_pt",
            strategy="forward",
        )
    )
    return result
```

We can now cut our DataFrame with a single call.

Below, we'll call the function without specifying any labels, allowing the function to create default labels.  And notice that we don't have to worry about our list of break points being floats - the function will automatically cast the values to `pl.Float64`.

```py
cut_dataframe(df, "var1", [-1, 1])
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ var1      ┆ break_pt ┆ category     │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ cat          │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ -1.265421 ┆ -1.0     ┆ (-inf, -1.0] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.703735 ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.535669 ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1257    ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.361595  ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.947081  ┆ 1.0      ┆ (-1.0, 1.0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.304     ┆ inf      ┆ (1.0, inf]   │
└───────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

And here, we'll pass in a list of labels.

```py
cut_dataframe(df, "var1", [-1, 1], ["low", "med", "hi"])
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ var1      ┆ break_pt ┆ category │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ cat      │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ -1.265421 ┆ -1.0     ┆ low      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.703735 ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.535669 ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.132105 ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1049    ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.1257    ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.361595  ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.640423  ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.947081  ┆ 1.0      ┆ med      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.304     ┆ inf      ┆ hi       │
└───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Hopefully, the above is more helpful.

Comment: I've added some improvements that may help, particularly labels.